# Is there any difference between these two loops?

Tags: java, performance, loops

Is there any difference performance-wise between the two code snippets below?

```
for(String project : auth.getProjects()) {
    // Do something with 'project'
}
```

and

```
String[] projects = auth.getProjects();
for(String project : projects) {
    // Do something with 'project'
}
```

For me, I think the second one is better, but it is longer. The first one is shorter, but I am not really sure if it is faster. I am not sure, but to me it seems like every time that loop is iterated, `auth.getProjects` is called. Is that not so?

Comment: It is only called once, but the second version is far too verbose. All you're doing is going through a list. One line is enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit**: [@StephenC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452537/is-there-any-difference-between-these-two-loops/23452617?noredirect=1#comment-35951716) is right, the JLS is a much better place to find an answer for something of this nature. Here is a [link to the enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) in the language specification. In there you will find that there are a few different types of for statements it generates but none of them would  call the method more than 1 time.

---

Simple test shows that the method is only called once

```
public class TestA {
    public String [] theStrings;

    public TestA() {
        theStrings = new String[] {"one","two", "three"};
        for(String string : getTheStrings()) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }

    public String[] getTheStrings() {
        System.out.println("get the strings");
        return theStrings;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new TestA();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
get the strings
one
two
three
```

So essentially they are the same thing. The only thing that may be beneficial about the 2nd would be if you want to use the array outside the for loop.

---

**Edit**

You got me curious about how the java compiler handled this so using the code above I decompiled the class file and heres what the result is

```
public class TestA
{

    public TestA()
    {
        String as[];
        int j = (as = getTheStrings()).length;
        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            String string = as[i];
            System.out.println(string);
        }

    }

    public String[] getTheStrings()
    {
        System.out.println("get the strings");
        return theStrings;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new TestA();
    }

    public String theStrings[] = {
        "one", "two", "three"
    };
}
```

As you can see the compiler simply restructured your for loop into a standard loop! It also further proves that in fact they are exactly the same after the compiler gets through with it.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have a clear idea what really goes on behind the scenes.

Comment: *"Simple test shows that the method is only called once"* - Simple tests can be misleading ... 'cos you don't know what you should be testing.  A better approach is to read the JLS.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few more operations in the second example. Instead of referencing the array directly using the method, you are declaring a new reference variable, storing it in that new variable, then referencing the new variable.

You can check out the bytecode with ASM Bytecode Outline.

BUT, this is micro-optimization. If you need a new reference variable, then create one. If you don't need one, save the work and don't create a new one.

Comment: Did you mean "second example" instead of "first example"?  The second example is the one that declares a new reference variable.  Although, if the reference variable is not used elsewhere in the function, most compilers would likely use a register for it in either case.

Answer (score 3):

Assumng that by `in` you mean `:`, there is no difference in performance; they both do the same thing.  Even in the first example, auth.getProjects() is executed only once; it can't be executed multiple times, since if it was, the `for` iteration would have to start over each time, which is not how it works.

I'd recommend using the version you find to be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

According to the [JLS 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), an enhanced `for` loop (for an array type) is equivalent to a regular `for` loop with the following pattern:

```
T[] #a = Expression;
L1: L2: ... Lm:
for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
    Statement
}
```

If we substitute for your first example:

```
for(String project : auth.getProjects()) {
   // Do something with 'project'
}
```

we get:

```
String[] $a = auth.getProjects();
for (int $i = 0; $i < $a.length; $i++) {
    String project = $a[$i];
    // Do something with 'project'
}
```

For your second example:

```
String[] projects = auth.getProjects();
for(String project : projects) {
    // Do something with 'project'
}
```

we get:

```
String[] projects = auth.getProjects();
String[] $a = projects;
for (int $i = 0; $i < $a.length; $i++) {
    String project = $a[$i];
    // Do something with 'project'
}
```

The two versions of the code are clearly equivalent, and assuming that `javac` or the JIT is capable of optimizing away the redundant local variable `$a`, the two versions should perform the same.

Note that the local variable `$a` is only created once at the start of the loop in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

The second one is better performance-wise, it is not creating a variable multiple times.  Therefore, yes, auth.getProjects is being called every time.

Comment: Incorrect.  The local variable to hold `auth.getProjects()` is created and assigned just once.  See my Answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wrote that at night xD

Answer (score -1):

Both are same as found above.

But do one thing use 1st approcah and after the for loop, de-reference the projects variable as-
projects = null;
Else, it will stay alive for the complete method life and will consume unnecessary memory.

Comment: Incorrect.  The getProjects method is not called "in the loop".  It is called once, at the start of the loop.